# Using maven, how to concat final name of war with project version in a specific format?

Tags: maven

The functionality of Parallel Deployment from Tomcat requires that the .war file name be in a specific format.

For example: If we have the version 1 of the project running and we need to hot deploy the version 2, it is needed that the .war name be "project-name##2.war".

We use in our project [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/). So our versions are for example *5.31.6* .

When we deploy a new version through Tomcat manager we build the project using maven, rename the file name to `project-name##053106.war` and upload it to server. This process is manual and susceptible to errors.

Our version is set in `pom.xml` like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-name</artifactId>
    <version>5.31.6</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Project Name</name>
    <description>Project Description</description>
    ...
</project>
```

We set the final name in profiles, for example:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <profilelabel>LOCAL</profilelabel>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <finalName>project-name-local</finalName>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <profilelabel>PRODUCTION</profilelabel>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <finalName>project-name</finalName>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

My question is: With the examples above, how can I build the war file with the final name concatenated with version number without the dots and if possible with each "part" of version "str_pad"ed (5.31.6 becomes 053106)?

- Using profile local: project-name-local##053106.war
- Using profile prod: project-name##053106.war

Comment: What are you really trying to do, aside from having different names? Generally it is better if you can have one artifact that runs everywhere and externalise everything else (such as configuration).

Comment: To use the hot deploy feature from Tomcat it is required that the version number is appended to the file name, so the greatest version it will be the one that will receive the new sessions. What I want is to in the build process be able to automatically concat the version number to the generated WAR file and just upload it through manager.

Comment: I would like to see some documentation regarding "The functionality of hot deploy from Tomcat requires that the .war file name be in a specific format." I had never heard of it before so had a pretty good look through the the Apache Tomcat deployment documentation and found nothing regarding this...

Comment: @SteveC after doing some research I think I misused the term "hot deploy". Looking at the docs, the correct one is "Parallel deployment" and here is the link to the docs : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment
I should change it in the description of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gmaven plugin to mangle `project.version` in any desired way and assign it to a property (all during initialization phase). Here is an example,
it handles versions with `-SUFFIX` part (to be safe, it handles the case of multiple dashes):

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>yourProjectName-${paddedVersion}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>
                            println('Mangling project version: ' + project.version)
                            String[] versionParts = project.version.split("-")
                            paddedVersion = versionParts[0].split("\\.").collect { it.padLeft(2,"0") }.join()
                            if (versionParts.size() > 1) {
                                paddedVersion += "-" + versionParts[1..-1].join("-")
                            }
                            println('Padded version version: ' + paddedVersion)
                            project.properties["paddedVersion"] = paddedVersion
                        </source>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```